# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed when I'm creating a new category

Tags: django, django-models

I'm getting a FOREIGN KEY constraint failed error when I'm trying to create a new category in the admin panel, and this is the models.py file:

```
    `import datetime
from django.db import models
from UserAuthentication.models import User
from shortuuid.django_fields import ShortUUIDField
from django.utils.html import mark_safe

STATUS=(
    ("Vente", "Vente"),
    ("Location", "Location"),
)

Specification=(
    ("W/C douche", "W/C douche Interne"),
    ("W/C douche", "W/C douche Externe"),
    ("Eau", "Eau"),
    ("Cloture", "Cloture"),
    ("wifi", "Wifi"),
)

Bookings_status = (
    ("Accepter", "Accepter"),
    ("Refuser", "Refuser"),
    ("Traitement", "Traitement"),
)


def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

# Create your models here.
class CategorieBienImmobilier(models.Model):
    cid1 = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, length=10, max_length=30, prefix="cbi", alphabet='abcdefg12345') 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_directory_path')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categorie de bien Immobilier"

    def category_image(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50" />' % (self.picture.url))
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
class Ville(models.Model):
    Vid1 = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, length=10, max_length=30, prefix="vil", alphabet='abcdefg12345') 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_directory_path')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Ville"

    def ville_image(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50" />' % (self.picture.url))
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class BienImmobilier(models.Model):
    Bid =  ShortUUIDField(unique=True, length=10, max_length=30, prefix="bil", alphabet='abcdefg12345')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    proprietaire = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    categoriebienimmobilier = models.ForeignKey(CategorieBienImmobilier, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ville = models.ForeignKey(Ville, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=30)
    
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_directory_path', default="Bid.jpg")
    Prix = models.DecimalField(max_digits=999999, decimal_places=2)
    date_de_publication = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    specification = models.CharField(choices=Specification, max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Bien Immobilier"

    def getDateofPub():
        BIdate = BienImmobilier.date_de_publication
        ActualDate = datetime.date() 
        if BIdate < ActualDate :
            Typedepublication = 'Nouveau'
        elif BIdate == ActualDate:
            Typedepublication = 'Active'
        else:    
            Typedepublication = 'Ancien'

        return Typedepublication        

    def BI_image(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50" />' % (self.picture.url))
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 
    
    sku = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, length=10, max_length=30, prefix="sku", alphabet='abcdefg12345')


class Favories(models.Model):
    Fid = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, length=10, max_length=30, prefix="Fav", alphabet='abcdefg12345')   
    bienImmobilier = models.ForeignKey(BienImmobilier, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Favories"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.bienImmobilier.title
```

`
This is the error traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/MainApp/categoriebienimmobilier/add/

Django Version: 3.2.3
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['jazzmin',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'UserAuthentication',
 'crispy_forms',
 'MainApp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()

The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1657, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1540, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 246, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 266, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/MainApp/categoriebienimmobilier/add/
Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`
```

Does anyone have an Idea on how to solve this error? Please, I need help. I've searched on many forms, but none of them seem to be working.

Comment: Well, are your foreign key constraints satisfied? For instance, a `BienImmobilier` seems to require that an actual `Ville` with the given key exists if you include a value for `ville` in the record.